# IOCTL - Understanding file discriptor parameter

Tags: c, ioctl, low-level

Recently I came across ioctl function in c, while exploring I didn't understand why we are passing standard input file descriptor for this specific code and what is the role of it?.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
static void pr_winsize(int), sig_winch(int);
int main(void) {
if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) == 0) 
    exit(1);
if (signal(SIGWINCH, sig_winch) == SIG_ERR) 
    perror("signal error");
pr_winsize(STDOUT_FILENO); /* print initial size */ 
for ( ; ; ) /* and sleep forever */
pause(); 
}

static void pr_winsize(int fd) {
    struct winsize size;
    if (ioctl(fd, TIOCGWINSZ, (char *) &size) < 0) 
        perror("TIOCGWINSZ error");
    printf("%d rows, %d columns\n", size.ws_row, size.ws_col); }
static void sig_winch(int signo) {
    printf("SIGWINCH received\n"); 
    pr_winsize(STDIN_FILENO); 
    return;
}
```

Comment: `static void sig_winch(int signo) {
    printf("SIGWINCH received\n"); 
    pr_winsize(STDIN_FILENO); 
    return;
}`You should not call printf() and friends  from a signal handler. It is not async-safe.

Comment: unless you arewilling to juggle sigmask,but that could be in the code you did not show us ...

Comment: STDOUT_FILENO does not look like stdin to me, hard to guess why think it might be.  It is appropriate, stdout will refer to the terminal when output is not redirected.

Answer (score 1):

The TIOCGWINSZ command gets the screen (window) size of the file descriptor passed in. In this case, because stdin is being passed in, that's the terminal in which the program is running. The rest of the code is setting up a handler for the SIGWINCH (window change) handler, so that the size of the terminal is printed any time the terminal is resized.

Comment: I understood that part, but the code which I posted is not ideal solution, When I am running this code in CLion-Jetbrains I didn't get any output(May be because standard input file descriptor is changed by Clion) but it is running as expected in normal terminal. What can I do if I want to get screen size by running it anywhere?.

Comment: @konerunikhil I'm not sure about CLion internals, but it wouldn't surprise me if it does something simple (maybe a pipe, in which case your program would exit immediately, or a pseudo-TTY that doesn't send SIGWINCH).

Comment: What's the point of passing stdout or stderr fd? Isn't terminal size is by definition the size of a terminal in which programm is running?